# igraph R and C, writing and reading adjacency matrix with attributes

Tags: c, r, igraph, adjacency-matrix

I would like to use igraph R to visualize a network graph which I create with igraph C.

So far I have saved the graph in C with these commands:

```
FILE *ofile;
ofile=fopen("AdjacencyMatrix.csv", "w"); 
igraph_write_graph_pajek(&g, ofile);
fclose(ofile);
```

And then read the file from R with this one:

```
g<- read.graph("AdjacencyMatrix.csv", format = c("pajek"))
```

which works fine.

Now I would like to add attributes to the edges in order to distinguish between two groups of edges. In order to do so I am using 
the example from the igraph C Tutorial 'Example 12.2.  File examples/simple/cattributes2.c' and just add the above mentioned lines at the end
to save the graph in a csv file. Now two problems arise:

a) If I use the pajek command to save the file, the saved file does not contain any of the attributes but just the connections

b) If I use 'igraph_write_graph_graphml(&g, ofile, /*prefixattr=*/ 1);' instead, I am getting the following error message when trying to read
the file in igraph R:

```
g<- read.graph("AdjacencyMatrix.csv", format = c("graphml"))
```

Warning message:
In .Call("R_igraph_read_graph_graphml", file, as.numeric(index),  :
  At foreign-graphml.c:443 :Could not add vertex ids, there is already an 'id' vertex attribute

Does anyone have a suggestion how I can solve either of the problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re a): the Pajek format does not support arbitrary attributes, only a few dedicated ones; see the documentation of [`igraph_read_graph_pajek`](http://igraph.org/c/doc/igraph-Foreign.html#igraph_read_graph_pajek) for more details.

Re b): The message that you get is not an error message but only a warning. Feel free to ignore it - the graph is probably loaded just fine.

Comment: a) I will consult the documentation
b) You were absolutely right, thank you so much!!! I should have read the message more carefully.